# How to configure consul to access webpage from Ingress gateway

Tags: kubernetes, service, consul, aks

I am trying to configure ingress gateway for consul deployed in AKS.

As per their [documentation](https://www.consul.io/docs/k8s/connect/ingress-gateways) , I have created a sample deployment and ingress gateway to it.

yaml files: [github](https://github.com/thunderbirds-2021/consul-testing/tree/main/static-app)

```
kubectl apply -f static-app/
```

I changed the static app service from CluserIP to LoadBalancer and can get the page using `http://<LB_IP>`

But, with ingress gateway, I can access only by adding the header as below:

```
curl -H "Host: static-server.ingress.consul" "http://<IG_IP>:8080"
```

If I try without header, it is not getting the page.

Any suggestion on how to make it work without header, so that I can utilize the same for my main application.

Once, it is deployed, I am able to see in the consul window and got the IP address of the ingress-gateway using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the `IngressGateway` resource. Add the [Hosts](https://www.consul.io/docs/connect/config-entries/ingress-gateway#hosts) array with the wildcard specifier (`*`) and then apply the changes.

```
$ cat ingress-gateway.yaml
apiVersion: consul.hashicorp.com/v1alpha1
kind: IngressGateway
metadata:
  name: ingress-gateway
spec:
  listeners:
    - port: 8080
      protocol: http
      services:
        - name: static-server
          hosts:
          - "*"
      
$ kubectl apply -f ingress-gateway.yaml
ingressgateway.consul.hashicorp.com/ingress-gateway configured
```

We can check if it works as expected:

```
$ curl http://<IG_IP>:8080
"hello world"
```

Comment: THank you it worked but the labelling is bit confusing. I tried creating a different service again and added one more listener to the k8s, but it is not routing. Ignore the port in the ingress as I just changed for testing. Please suggest how to set this. https://github.com/thunderbirds-2021/consul-testing/tree/main/static-app2

Comment: @uday If my answer was helpful to you please consider accepting the answer or vote on it. If you have another question, please create a new question. That way it would be more clear and visible for the rest of the community.